# iGraph, R - sub-incidence matrices from bipartite groups (without computing entire incidence matrix)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, igraph, bipartite

Starting from two data.frames `df1` and `df2` with join keys between them, I end up with a data.frame like the following

```
# df3
#        V    ID1    X     ID2
# 1     V1    1      X2    12
# 2     V2    2      X1    11
# 3     V2    2      X2    12
# 4     V3    3      X2    12
# 5     V2    2      X3    13
# 6     V4    4      X3    13
# 7     V5    5      X4    14
# 8     V6    6      X4    14
# 9     V7    7      X5    15
# 10    V8    8      X5    15
# 11    V9    9      X5    15
# 12    V8    8      X6    16
# 13   V10    10     X6    16
```

where columns `V` and `X` identify the two groups of a bipartite graph and rows the edges. (I add two columns `ID1` and `ID2` for the next) From this I'd need to get the bipartite graph (BG) as intermediate step and then the incidence matrices of all the clusters (maximum independent vertices).

For obtaining the BG, I'd use

```
df4 <- subset(df3, select=c("ID1","ID2"))
bg <- make_bipartite_graph(c(rep(0,nrow(df1)),rep(1,now(df2))), c(t(df4)))
```

First question, is there any other smarter method to get the bipartite graph from my data.frame without using ID-columns but directly `V` and `X`?

Then, for the clusters I'd use `clusters` function but I don't know how to do in order to get then the subsets of the incidence matrix (without obtaining the entire one as it could be way too big). Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno if I got you right, but maybe you want

```
library(igraph)
df <- df3[, c(1, 3)]
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
V(g)$type <- substr(V(g)$name, 1, 1)=="V"
plot(as.undirected(g), layout=layout.bipartite(g)[, 2:1])
```

[image]

```
gs <- decompose(g)
lapply(gs, as_incidence_matrix)
# [[1]]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# X2  1  1  1  0
# X1  0  1  0  0
# X3  0  1  0  1
# 
# [[2]]
#    V5 V6
# X4  1  1
# 
# [[3]]
#    V7 V8 V9 V10
# X5  1  1  1   0
# X6  0  1  0   1
```

Comment: EXACTLY this! thanks a lot and sorry, I re-read my post and I honestly dunno how you got what I meant!! :)